# Handling ActiveX events on an Access form

Tags: ms-access, activex, ms-access-2007, vba

I have an ActiveX control for opening and manipulating a proprietary image type. I am able to embed the control in an Access form, and by using the Object Browser am able to ascertain all the class members. The only problem I am having is handling some of the events raised by the control.

For example, from the Object Browser I can see the following event definition:

```
Event RightClicked()
```

And when I add the following code to the form:

```
Private Sub CtrlInstanceName_RightClicked()
  'Anything here
End Sub
```

Everything works as expected. However, if the event declaration has parameters passed to it, such as:

```
Event MeasurementUpdated(id as Long)
```

Adding:

```
Private Sub CtrlInstanceName_MeasurementUpdated(id as Long)
  'Anything here
End Sub
```

Produces the following error:

> The expression ... you entered as the event property setting produced
>   the following error: Procedure declaration does not match description
>   of event or procedure having the same name.

Even more strange after adding this second handler, **all event handlers** on the form produce this error, including events raised by the form and other controls on the form.

I have tested the ActiveX control in a C# .NET application and am able to handle the events there (although they don't quite work as expected). In Visual Studio, the function prototypes end up being a little odd with auto-defined event handler class types.

Any ideas on how I need to change the event procedure declaration to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well like most Friday questions, I later found the answer to this one was rather quite simple.

First, due to my unfamiliarity with the VBA code editor, I did not know that it was possible to create stubs for embedded controls by using the Object combobox above the code. After selecting my control name I selected the `MeasurementUpdate` event from the procedure combobox.

The correct declaration is simply:

```
Private Sub CtrlInstanceName_MeasurementUpdated(ByVal id as Long)
  'Anything here
End Sub
```

The key difference being the `ByVal` modifier.